# How can I get two onClick calls to fire?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

Firstly I am not a web developer, I'm an Analytics professional, so I apologise if this question seems basic and not using the correct terminology!...

I am trying to get `_trackEvent` code to fire 'onClick' for some Social buttons - however as the social buttons open in a new window they already run an onClick as follows....

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.londonpass.com/infographic/hampton-court.html&title=Hampton Court - History and Stories Infographic from the London Pass/','newWin','width=400,height=200')" class="facebook"></a>
```

I need to add in the following `_trackEvent` code:

```
onClick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EN', 'Tower of London', 'Facebook']);
```

So what I am trying to do is fire an event to Google Analytics on click whilst not disturbing the button functionality. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I believe so - I have only check using builtwith.com as I don't have access to the developer on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick JavaScript/HTML lesson : what the contents of the inline "onclick"-attribute describe is the body of a "callback" function (a method that, in this case, is executed when the element is clicked). In this case it opens the Facebook share URL in a new window/tab when the anchor is clicked.

What you want to do is execute TWO different callbacks for the single click-event. This would lead us to using JavaScript to assign the event callbacks using "addEventListener/attachEvent" as the inline "onclick"-attribute only allows for a single callback handler, while adding listeners gives you the benefit of being able to add multiple callbacks for a single event type. As others have mentioned, if you have jQuery or another library available this can be a doddle to attach.

However, if you want a quick and dirty fix without getting too much JavaScript code going on outside of your HTML document, you can add the _gaq-tracking code inside the "onclick"-attribute by appending after the existing onclick-code like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.londonpass.com/infographic/hampton-court.html&title=Hampton Court - History and Stories Infographic from the London Pass/','newWin','width=400,height=200');_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EN', 'Tower of London', 'Facebook']);" class="facebook"></a>
```

Which will result in tracking the click in Analytics AND the window openeing. Semantically, this is quite fugly as it describes multiple handlers in a single of code, but for the sake of argument we assume you don't mind as the HTML had inline JS handling to begin with and we haven't even touched the subject of window opens being blocked when they are delegated through multiple functions instead of on a direct-click handler! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the tracking command before the window open command in the onClick
like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EN', 'Tower of London', 'Facebook']);window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.londonpass.com/infographic/hampton-court.html&title=Hampton Court - History and Stories Infographic from the London Pass/','newWin','width=400,height=200')" class="facebook"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onclick`, attach the events **using jquery if you have it:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.facebook').on('click', function () {
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.londonpass.com/infographic/hampton-court.html&title=Hampton Court - History and Stories Infographic from the London Pass/','newWin','width=400,height=200')
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EN', 'Tower of London', 'Facebook']);

    //other code you like
});
</script>
```

**For attaching the event using pure javascript:**

```
var socials = document.getElementByClass("facebook");
socials.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

And define your function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction () {
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.londonpass.com/infographic/hampton-court.html&title=Hampton Court - History and Stories Infographic from the London Pass/','newWin','width=400,height=200')
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EN', 'Tower of London', 'Facebook']);

        //other code you like
}
</script>
```

Comment: It might be better to suggest to a self-described "non-web developer" to use a library (that is probably present) over using the vanilla JavaScript approach as the example omits the use of "attachEvent" rather than "addEventListener" for Internet Explorer, and the catching of the socials element being null (as the "getElementByClass"-lookup could have returned no results).